# ArrrayList use for user defined Class

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

I'm facing a problem in ArrrayList. Please help.

A test program in which has  two data type  String and int,
when add item by add method it give me error;
if Integer is add The method add(int, Test) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int)
and if String is add it give 
The method add(Test) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)

```
public cl* Test {
String firstName;
int rollNum;

public static void main(String[] args) {//this ArrayList work fine



ArrayList<Integer> Num=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
    Num.add(i);

}
for (int i = 0; i < Num.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(Num.get(i));
}//this ArrayList work fine



ArrayList<String> Num2=new ArrayList<String>();
Num2.add("ali");
Num2.add("2");

ArrayList<Test> Num1=new ArrayList<Test>();
Num1.add("Char"); // now it generate Error
```

}

Comment: You declared Num1 as an ArrayList of Test objects, but you're adding a String object, not a Test object.

Comment: `ArrayList<Test>` is suppose to hold only objects of `Test` type. Since `String` is not `Test` type you cant add it to such list. You can add only instances of `Test` class.

Comment: Hi! Could you please edit your question to make it more grammatically correct and with formatted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> a   means -> Creating an ArrayList of Integer objects.
ArrayList<String> b    means -> Creating an ArrayList of String objects.
```

Similarly,

```
ArrayList<Test> c      means -> Creating an ArrayList of Test objects.
```

So, you need to create a Test object to add it to the c list as it demands a Test object.

Now,

```
/* If you have this parameterized constructor. 
   I suggest you to have it if you dont have. */
Test obj = new Test("Fname",10);
```

obj can be inserted now in the c object. This could be implemented using the add method of the 
ArrayList class.

```
c.add(obj); //Adds the object 'obj' to the ArrayList 'c'
```

This won't give error.

Answer (score 1):

In the last statement you have created an array list of type `Test`

```
ArrayList<Test> Num1=new ArrayList<Test>();
```

So insert `Test` objects into it

For eg:-

```
Test test = new Test();
test.setFirstName("ABC");
test.setRollNo(23);

ArrayList<Test> Num1 = new ArrayList<Test>();
Num1.add(test);
```